# Converting from doxygen comments in visual studio c#, to javadoc comments in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2012, javadoc, doxygen

I am porting doxygen documentation from visual studio c# project to java eclipse project.
Can you please suggest tutorials or some guides for mapping the one style of comments
to the other?

For example, how do I translate this doxygen comment to javadoc comment?

/// the custom solution data type, derived from Solution

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking from the perspective of one who has tried to map from doxygen (in C) to javadoc I think you will find this direction remarkably difficult, especially if you have much narrative in your original commentary.  I find javadoc dreadfully lacking in most of the capabilities of doxygen, so really only the absolute minimum commentary can be usefully transferred - things like @param, @return etc.  I've never found any good tutorials, or even any bad ones.  I suspect this isn't something people do by choice.

Consider whether you could continue to use doxygen.  Doxygen interprets all the javadoc commands (at least all the ones I've come across), and you can benignly add doxygen '\'-style commands into the java commentary without upsetting any existing javadoc processing.

*Edit: Just to clarify that point slightly. Javadoc won't have warnings or errors as a result of using \command entries, but the \command text will emerge in the javadoc output as text.*

The downside, of course, is that *javadoc* is needed if you want pop-ups in your IDE (e.g. Eclipse) so if that's a requirement then using doxygen instead won't be much use.  However, if you just need to create good quality HTML documentation / manuals with diagrams and narrative then it might be an option.